# GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS where is it?

Tags: mac-osx, google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface

I am trying to follow the directions to use cloud translation.

At https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-protocol?hl=en_US are the instructions, but I am not clear on these.

I have succeeded with the first stop of downloading the JSON key, but where do I go to set the environmental variable?

I am running Mac OSX Catalina.

Answer (score 2):

For MacOS, Open a terminal window, then type the following:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"
```

For example:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/my-key.json"
```